# How do we prove that the different definitions of the derivative are equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was thinking about the different definitions of the derivative, and by using geometric arguments you can convince yourself that
\begin{align} f'(x) = \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+ah) - f(x-bh)}{(a+b)h}, \end{align}
for any choice of positive (or $0$) $a$ and $b$. However, is it possible to rigorously prove that these definitions of the derivative are the same, regardless of $a$ and $b$? I've tried for quite a while now, and seeing as \begin{align} f'(x) = \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \end{align}
and
\begin{align} f'(x) = \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h} \end{align}
are both quite common definitions, it seems important that we be sure they are the same thing.

Any ideas on the proof of this?

Comment: Think about $f(x) = \vert x\vert$. As $x\to 0$, the first definition does not exist, but the second one is always $0$. So the definitions are not the same. In fact, this is the reason the first definition is preferred.

Comment: The limits you give in your question can't be used to define derivative due to a very obvious reason. Derivative also deals with value of function at that point and your limits do not deal with function value at the point under consideration.

Comment: If the function is derivable then both of them are equal

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$\Delta=f(x+ah)-f(x-bh)=(f(x+ah)-f(x))-(f(x-bh)-f(x))$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+ah)-f(x)}{ah}=f'(x)$$

So,

$$f(x+ah)-f(x)=$$
$$ahf'(x)+h\epsilon_1(h)$$

and

$$f(x-bh)-f(x)=$$
$$-bhf'(x)+h\epsilon_2(h))$$

thus

$$\Delta=(a+b)hf'(x)+h\epsilon(h)$$
Done.

Answer (score 0):

The two definitions are identical if you consider the domain of problems for which they are applied - problems where $$\lim_{x\to x_0^+} = \lim_{x\to x_0^-}.$$  However, in other situations, those two definitions are not exactly identical. Think about $y = |x|$ at $x = 0$.  The former will give you $1$ and the latter will give you $0$.

EDIT - commenter is correct, the former only gives $1$ if it is $\lim_{h\to 0^+}$.  It is undefined otherwise.

Comment: Actually, $\lim _{h \to 0} \frac{|x+h| - |x|}{h}$ is undefined at $x=0$. You may be thinking of $\lim _{h \to 0^+} \frac{|x+h| - |x|}{h}$.